# Using Python and Xpath, how can I write empty values to the correct row when reading data from an XML file and outputting to an Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, xml, xpath

My Python code below outputs the data in three columns: column=1 for the wnc90Value values, column=2 for the wnc90Docid values, and column=3 for the wnc90Expheading values. The wnc90Value, wnc90Docid, and wnc90Expheading values for each //node[starts-with(local-name(), "level")] should be on the same row. When there is no wnc90Expheading value, "N/A" should be entered in column=3 of the row with the corresponding wnc90Value and wnc90Docid values. However, instead, it is being added to the last row of column=3 no matter which //node[starts-with(local-name(), "level")] it belongs to.

Here is the Python code I tried:

```
from lxml import etree
import glob
from openpyxl import Workbook
from pathlib import Path
import re

# Path to XML file
path="C:\\Users\\x\\x\\x\\x\\TestXML\\x.xml"

# Filename of XML file
fileName = Path(path).name

# Create a new workbook and rename the active worksheet
workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active
worksheet.title = "WNC90"

# Save the workbook
workbook.save('Results - Detailed (' + fileName + ').xlsx')

# Write headers to worksheet
worksheet['A1'] = "metadata value"
worksheet['B1'] = "exp-level ID"
worksheet['C1'] = "exp-level heading"

# Initialize the row number to start writing data
row_num = 2

for file in glob.glob(path):
    
    parser = etree.XMLParser(load_dtd=True, resolve_entities=False)
    tree = etree.parse(file, parser=parser)
    root = tree.getroot()

    # Get the wnc90 values for the level elements   
    wnc90Value = root.xpath('.//*[starts-with(local-name(), "level")]/ext-metadata/ext-meta-object/ext-meta-attrs/ext-meta-attr[@value="ThreeMonthItem" or @value="FifteenMonthItem"]/@value')
    
    # Get the docID values for the level elements with wnc90 metadata
    wnc90Docid = root.xpath('.//*[starts-with(local-name(), "level")][ext-metadata/ext-meta-object/ext-meta-attrs/ext-meta-attr[@value="ThreeMonthItem" or @value="FifteenMonthItem"]]/@id')
    
    # Get the heading in the level elements with wnc90 metadata 
    wnc90Expheading = root.xpath('.//*[starts-with(local-name(), "level")][ext-metadata/ext-meta-object/ext-meta-attrs/ext-meta-attr[@value="armacThreeMonthItem" or @value="FifteenMonthItem"]]/heading[1]')
     
    # Write data to worksheet
    for i in range(len(wnc90Docid)):
        worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=1, value=wnc90Value[i])
        worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=2, value=wnc90Docid[i])
        
        if i < len(wnc90Expheading):
            worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=3, value=wnc90Expheading[i].text)  
        else:
            worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=3, value="N/A")                          
            
        row_num += 1

# Save the workbook
workbook.save('Results - Detailed (' + fileName + ').xlsx')
```

I also tried if len(wnc90Expheading) > i instead of if i < len(wnc90Expheading), but got the same result.

Here is the actual output:

```
data = {'metadata value': [ThreeMonthItem, ThreeMonthItem, FifteenMonthItem],
    'level ID': [FB8404BF64C8C724862584BD0059BABD, A38592747306A36786257E290059CDF4, 51B86B7505A5F8BE862588AA006A6F53],
    'level heading': [Discussion, B.1-B.19 Appendix B, N/A]}
```

Here is the expected output:

```
data = {'metadata value': [ThreeMonthItem, ThreeMonthItem, FifteenMonthItem],
    'level ID': [FB8404BF64C8C724862584BD0059BABD, A38592747306A36786257E290059CDF4, 51B86B7505A5F8BE862588AA006A6F53],
    'level heading': [Discussion, N/A, B.1-B.19 Appendix B, ]}
```

Here is what the XML looks like (as you can see, the empty heading is skipped in column 3 of the Excel file and moved to the bottom of the column):

```
<root>
    <level-1 id="FB8404BF64C8C724862584BD0059BABD">
        <heading>Discussion</heading>
        <ext-metadata>
            <ext-meta-object>
                <ext-meta-attrs>
                    <ext-meta-attr value="ThreeMonthItem"/>
                </ext-meta-attrs>
            </ext-meta-object>
        </ext-metadata>
    </level-1>
    <level-1 id="A38592747306A36786257E290059CDF4">
        <ext-metadata>
            <ext-meta-object>
                <ext-meta-attrs>
                    <ext-meta-attr value="ThreeMonthItem"/>
                </ext-meta-attrs>
            </ext-meta-object>
        </ext-metadata>
    </level-1>
    <level-2 id="51B86B7505A5F8BE862588AA006A6F53">
        <heading>B.1-B.19 Appendix B</heading>
        <ext-metadata>
            <ext-meta-object>
                <ext-meta-attrs>
                    <ext-meta-attr value="FifteenMonthItem"/>
                </ext-meta-attrs>
            </ext-meta-object>
        </ext-metadata>
    </level-2>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi @user4504522! Some advice re your question: your XML sample would be improved by making it into well-formed XML. As it stands, it has no root element, and it's missing closing tags for several elements. Also, you've provided sample output in the form of images, which is not recommended. You can use markdown to create a table, instead, which will allow us to read both samples at once and compare them. If you would edit your question to fix the XML and improve the output examples you'd be more likely to get more (and better) answers.

Comment: @user:7372462 Thanks for your comment. I've edited my question. Hope it's ok.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're trying to do, still, but if I were you I would execute an XPath to retrieve the `level-n` elements, retrieve that nodeset, then iterate over it in your Python code, executing XPath queries relative to each of those elements (instead of the document `root` node), to retrieve individual values. That will make each row independent of the others.